# Get table column by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup

I need to make "bold" the second column of this html table:
http://jsfiddle.net/beKC4/4/

How can I do using JQuery? 
I tried this but is not working:

```
$("h3.ms-standardheader").children("td").text("<b>"+this.text()+"</b>")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use css

see here http://jsfiddle.net/beKC4/6/

```
table tr td:nth-child(3){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Note that browser support of `:nth-child` in IE < 9 is limited. Don't know what all the OP needs to support but this may be a factor.

Comment: Solved using table tr td:first-child + td + td

Answer (score 2):

Use `.html()` instead

```
$(".ms-standardheader").closest('tr').find("td").html(function () {
    return "<b>" + $(this).text() + "</b>"
});
```

Also, the selector is incorrect, you need to use closest, then find the `<td>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/beKC4/10/)

Or if you don't want ms-standardheader to also get `<b>` you can use siblings()

```
$(".ms-standardheader").closest('td').siblings("td").html(function () {
    return "<b>" + $(this).text() + "</b>"
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/beKC4/15/)

Comment: it s still not working, i think that the problem is to reach the elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Create a css class and add this class with js using [:nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). Think is simplier.

**css**

```
.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**js**

```
$('table td:nth-child(3)').addClass('bold');
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/beKC4/18/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/b4AwC/

I would use nthchild selector, if you want ever other one bold you can put in even or odd
I hope this help

```
$("tr td:nth-child(2)").css({"color":"red"});
$("tr td:nth-child(even)").css({"background":"grey"});
```